# Accessible square on a chessboard that has 5 different visual states

Tags: accessibility, web, wcag

I want to make an accessible chess board. A square (`div`) can have 5 different, visual states:

- not selected and not colored
- selected
- colored 3 different ways (e.g. green, red and blue)

The colors are a problem for people who are visually impaired and I want to find a solution where this feature is accessible to them too.

The screenshot below is an example of how this looks like on lichess.org. The square with pawn in front of the king is selected, and in the center of the board there are the 3 ways you can color a square.

By pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>, you can select/deselect a square. By pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd>, you can cycle through the different colors (including no color).

The selected/not selected can be handled using the `aria-selected` state. But how can I indicate that a square can be colored 3 different ways?

`role="button"` doesn't seem correct, because there is no immediate action associated with it. And it depends whether `ctrl` is pressed or not.

Maybe `role="spinbutton"`? But the `aria-valuenow` is supposed to be a decimal, and the keyboard interactions don't fit.

So I'm a bit at a loss. How can I have these states and stay accessible?

I'm currently leaning towards a visually hidden set of radio buttons, each indicating the current color.

[image: Chess board with different highlights]

---

Example HTML:

- The user has selected the `a1` square that has a piece on it
- The user has colored the `b1` square red
- The user has colored the `c1` square green
- The user has colored the `d1` square blue
- Using keyboard navigation, the user has the focus on the `e1` square

```html
<div role="grid" aria-colcount="8" aria-rowcount="8" aria-activedescendant="e1">
  <div id="a1" tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-label="a1" aria-selected="true" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+Space Space">
    <!-- aria-selected="true" indicates that the piece on that square has been selected -->
  </div>

  <div id="b1" tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-label="b1" aria-selected="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+Space Space">
    <!-- How to tell the user that this square is colored red, and ctrl+space will set it to green? -->
  </div>

  <div id="c1" tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-label="c1" aria-selected="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+Space Space">
    <!-- How to tell the user that this square is colored green, and ctrl+space will set it to blue? -->
  </div>

  <div id="d1" tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-label="d1" aria-selected="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+Space Space">
    <!-- How to tell the user that this square is colored blue, and ctrl+space will remove the color? -->
  </div>

  <div id="e1" tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-label="d1" aria-selected="false" aria-keyshortcuts="Control+Space Space">
    <!-- This square has the focus, as indicated by activedescendant="e1" -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the chessboard implemented? As a <table>? A screen reader user can easily navigate a table by moving across a table row or down a table column. I would think you'd have the "name" of each chessboard location as the table cell name ("a4", "d2", etc). Or that can be accomplished by having appropriate row and column headers (<th scope="row">). The "state" of each square could be handled by visibly hidden screen reader text. You mentioned some keyboard interactions. Would the user use the arrow keys to navigate to a square and then press ENTER or Ctrl+ENTER?

Comment: I'm limited in what I can comment on in this section but I had lots of questions that I didn't think was appropriate to ask in the "answer" area.  Is each chess piece a <button> in a table cell?  As a sighted keyboard user, would I arrow (up/down/left/right) to the piece I want to move, select it, then move somewhere on the board and select the destination?

Comment: @slugolicious It is implemented as a set of nested divs. The keyboard navigation is already implemented, including showing a focus ring, as well as having the coordinates as aria-label. Once navigated to the correct square, they can use ENTER to select/deselect it (like the pawn in front of the king), or CTRL+ENTER to cycle through the different states (like in the center of the board). But I don't see how I can communicate this to the user.

Comment: *"The keyboard navigation is already implemented"*. Is that done by listening for keyboard events and then you move the focus to the appropriate square? Each square would need `tabindex="-1"` (to allow programmatic/javascript focus) to work on all browsers. If the user can navigate to each square, what [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) is announced for the square in order to satisfy WCAG [4.1.2 Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#name-role-value)?

Comment: That is where I'm currently stuck. Since it is wrapped in `div` with `role="grid"`, I have put `role="griditem"`, but that doesn't tell the user anything about how it can be selected/colorized

Comment: Do you have a working example to try? It's much easier to analyze and comment on that rather than trying to explain things in text.

Answer (score 1):

### Question

What is the significance of the three colors? Is there any significance between the red green and blue? Or are these just user markers?

## Multi-State Stuff

That said, based on your screen shot you have additional problems.

First, let's take a look at that board though an accurate colorblind simulator:

[image: A simulation of the chessboard with normal upper left, then protan and other forms of CVD]

Standard vision is upper left, then protanopia upper right. Processed using the [Myndex CVD sim](https://www.myndex.com/CVD/)

As you can see, your green is so close to the dark square color it's almost indistinguishable. Do you want to choose marker colors that have a significant enough luminance difference from the board that those with color insensitivity can still perceive them.

Using a contrast calculator, set the background color as the square color, and then find a color for the graphic that is at least Lc ±30 (or more for thinner graphics).

### Color Differentiation

If the re, gree, blue have a specific meaning, i.e. the red means a bad move, the blue means a weak move, and the green is the best move, then you need to add an additional identifier to convey that information.

Example, instead of a dot for all three colors, use an octogon with red, and triangle for blue, and a star for green. This provides the additional information for those that are insensitive to hue differences.

#### Spatial Note

Also, we can detect hue differences better with lower spatial resolutions. But we have a harder time with hue and saturation differences for thin elements.

So for instances, those rings, it's better if they are at least 6px wide, if they are using color in an informational way.

Comment: These are just user markers and have no predetermined meaning. I've noticed the problems with the color as well. In my defense, this is a screenshot of an existing site. I intend to do better. Using a contrast calculator and making the ring wider are good ideas that I haven't considered yet, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jeroen  for contrast calculators, I'll suggest the perceptual https://apcacontrast.com  ... Coming soon it will have an indicator that says how thick a line needs to be for a given contrast.

Comment: That seems to be a great resource. I've bookmarked it